# Jenkins shared library - create a generic function for the options section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I want to expand our shared library usage - want to add a function that will contain all the options for the pipeline:

```groovy
options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timestamps()
        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES')
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '30'))
    }
```

so in my pipeline I will have something like

```groovy
pipeline {
   agent any

   pipelineOptions()

   stages {
       stage('phase1') { 
           steps {               
               sh 'echo Hello World '
           }
       }
   }
}
```

tried something like , but it didn't work

```groovy
//pipelineOptions.groovy
def call() {
        options {
                disableConcurrentBuilds()
                timestamps()
                timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES')
                //buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: ' params.history'))
                buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: ' 5'))
        }

}
```

couldn't find how to make it ... , is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible today to define [sections](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-sections)/[directives](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-directives) of a declarative pipeline in a shared library. From the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines):

> Only entire pipeline's can be defined in shared libraries as of this time. This can only be done in `vars/*.groovy`, and only in a `call` method. Only one Declarative Pipeline can be executed in a single build, and if you attempt to execute a second one, your build will fail as a result.